# testng.xml is not running from pom.xml during executing selenium tests

Tags: eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng, pom.xml

I have created Maven project in Eclipse for executing Selenium tests. I have written a TestSuite as testng.xml. I like to run this testng.xml from pom.xml.

When I ran pom.xml (Right click pom.xml -> Maven test) the build was success, but no test was run. The test result is as follows:

### T E S T S

Results :
Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

My project structure is as follows:

[image]

My testng.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Regression Test" verbose="2">
    <test name="Google" preserve-order="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.ripon.selenium.google.Abcd" />
            <class name="com.ripon.selenium.google.GoogleTest2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ripon.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>SeleniumTestMaven</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>/src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                    <version>2.3.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>selenium-tests</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.12.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <suiteXmlFiles>
                                <suiteXmlFile>/src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                            </suiteXmlFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.8.8</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Rename your test into `GoogleTest.java` [based on the naming conventions](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes). Don't use maven-surefire-plugin to run integration tests (maven-failsafe-plugin). If you use maven-failse-plugin following naming conventions for integration tests. See docs for maven-failsafe-plugin

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise. I have renamed test file according to naming convention. I have renamed my test files as "AbcdTest.java" and "GoogleTest.java". After that my TestSuite is running well. No need to change/modify in my pom.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, The test class should end-up with Test [***Test**] for Maven; By default you will see a class name `AppTest`.

No Changes in **TestNG.xml**; Make sure your POM file looks similar to the below :) [I have seen you questioning yesterday via Skype group chat]

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>groupidhere</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactidhere</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>artifactidhere</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <inherited>true</inherited>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
           <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
        <configuration>                        
          <suiteXmlFiles>
               <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>              
          </suiteXmlFiles>         
        </configuration>       
      </plugin>   
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>           
    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>           
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.8</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
      <version>2.35.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>2.35.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
      <version>2.35.0</version>
    </dependency>           
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take out the slash at the start of src. / at the start would indicate an absolute path.

Comment: Thanks niharika_neo. But It works with or without slash (/). Main issues is for file name: postfix of file should be "Test"

Comment: As far as I know, the suite xml file is the thing that guides what classes to execute and not the naming conventions.  Annotations identify tests.  I regularly run tests from classes which do not contain the Test in the class name.  I somehow feel your suite xml file is not being referred still.

Comment: When I used Ant and TestNG, class naming convention is not a matter.

Comment: Yes, I am using maven.

Comment: Is your class name without postfix "Test"?

Comment: Yep, just to try out i purposefully renamed it to something without a test and the test ran successfully when i did mvn test with my suite xml specified.

Comment: Can you check if you increase the verbosity in your xml, does it reflect in the output just to see if your xml is being read?

Comment: Can you please provide your pom.xml and testng.xml?

Comment: <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <configuration>
     <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/TestNG-Params.xml</suiteXmlFile>
     </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

Comment: Testng xml : <suite name="My Suite1" parallel="methods" thread-count="5" >
 <test verbose="2" name="Default1 test">
  <parameter name="name" value="NotNiharika"></parameter>
  <parameter name="fname" value="Niharika"></parameter>
   <classes>
    <class name="com.nv.demo.testngtests.Params"/>
    
    </classes>
   </test>
 </suite>

Comment: Apologies for the delay. Busy day!